# php file not running on browser after configuring it with apache 2.2.22 and php 5.2.13

Tags: php, android, apache

I want to call php file form android app to fetch the data from the server so configure the apache 2.2.22 with php 5.2.13 and then i run the index page it run correctly and when try to run the project page it say server not found and in the error log file of the apache it show the following warnings:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/php/ext\\php_pdo_mssql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/php/ext\\php_pdo_oci.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/php/ext\\php_pdo_oci8.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

can anyone tell whats the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a server issue, and it seems that your library files are missing from your server extension folder

Comment: dll files are present in the folder...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have that .dll installed? If not then PHP will throw an error because it cannot load the proper libraries to use things like mysql_connect, etc.

try downloading the .dll again and seeing if it solves the problem.

What does your php.ini look like?

Try uncommenting this line:
;extension=php_mysql.dll
Save the ini and then restart Apache.

Try to put the libmysql.dll in c:/windows/system32 and then restart apache...

Comment: all the .dll files are installed correctly and libmysql file is also present in the system32 folder but still facing the same issue...

Comment: Copy the following files in System32 directory
1. libmysql.dll
2. msql.dll

Copy the following files in php\ext directory
1. msql.dll . This file should be copied when you extract the PHP 5 zip file, but obviously its not

Restart the World Wide Web Publishing Service under Administrative Tools > Services

Hope this works...